# Published Xamarin UWP app crashing on startup when built with Visual Studio 2019 16.10 or higher

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp, skiasharp

I have a working app that has previously been published to the Microsoft Store.  I attempted to upgrade my Visual Studio 2019 from a 16.9.10 version to 16.10.x (I've also tried the latest 16.11.2).  Everything was working in the debugger after the update for both debug and release builds.  However, when I tried to create a package for sideloading on another computer, I discovered the resulting package would crash on startup.  In addition, running the appxbundle on my development machine resulted in the same runtime crash.

Further digging showed that the app is crashing in Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init after throwing an ambiguous match found exception.  Printing the stacktrace and capturing with DebugView showed the following:

[15348] Ambiguous match found.

[15348] at System.Reflection.Runtime.Assemblies.RuntimeAssembly.GetRuntimeAssembly(RuntimeAssemblyName) + 0x25
[15348] at System.Reflection.Runtime.General.ReflectionCoreCallbacksImplementation.Load(AssemblyName, Boolean) + 0x1b
[15348] at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName) + 0x15
[15348] at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.WindowsBasePlatformServices.GetAssemblies() + 0x1dd
[15348] at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.Registrar.RegisterAll(Type[], InitializationFlags) + 0x6c
[15348] at Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(IActivatedEventArgs, IEnumerable`1) + 0x558

Has anyone experienced this?  Any suggestions on how to further troubleshoot the problem?

**Update: I am able to reproduce the problem in a blank project:**

Here are the steps to recreate:

1. Create a new c# Mobile Project (Xamarin.Forms).
2. In the shared project, add skiasharp nuget package.
3. Add new Windows Application Packaging Project to the solution.
4. Add reference to the UWP project from step 1 to the WAPP.  Right-click the WAPP project and publish it for side-loading.
5. Run the installer to install the app.
6. When the app is launched it will crash.
7. If skia-sharp is removed and the installer is rebuilt and run, the app will launch correctly.

Comment: Have you build package successfully in previous Visual Studio version?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Yes, as stated in my post I can publish the app successfully when I use 16.9.x.  However, yesterday I discovered a different bug in 16.9.10 that has brought me to a stand still.  The bug I'm up against has been fixed in the latest 16.10 version.  So now I'm stuck and need to figure out what the published app is crashing in 16.10.x.

Comment: If you have not updated your project, this problem is more related with Visual studio. we suggest repair the vs and build again. and please if you have refer to the package that does not support release mode.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I am able to reproduce the problem with a brand new solution.  Here are the steps to recreate:  1.  Create a new c# Mobile Project. 2. In the shared project, add skiasharp nuget package. 3. Add new Windows Application Packaging Project to the solution. 4. Add reference to the UWP project from step 1 to the WAPP.  Right-click the WAPP project and publish it for side-loading.  5. Run the installer to install the app.  6.  When the app is launched it will crash.  7.  If skia-sharp is removed and the installer is rebuilt and run, the app will launch correctly.

Comment: Ok, I got it, we will try reproduce it. any updates will update below.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Have you been able to look into this more?

Comment: It looks VS issue, please feel free post your feedback with Visual Studio help->send feedback.